# how to get the button value from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to get the button value from jsp to servlet
in jsp:

```
<input type=button name=bt value=gi onclick="document.frm.submit();"></input>
```

and in servlet like that:

```
String gi =request.getParameter("bt");
    System.out.print("button value" +gi);
```

result=null

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a hidden variable inside form and use it like this.

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnbt" />
<input type="button" name="bt" value="gi" onclick="{document.frm.hdnbt.value=this.value;document.frm.submit();}" />
</form>
```

Now, in the servlet,

```
String gi =request.getParameter("hdnbt");
System.out.print("button value" +gi);
```

Comment: Silly question, but can I expand this to several buttons? I have 6 buttons, each with their own function and would like to implement this where possible.

Answer (score 29):

Rather use `<input type="submit">`.

```
<input type="submit" name="bt" value="gi">
```

Its name/value pair will be sent to the server side as well:

```
String bt = request.getParameter("bt"); // gi
```

No need for JavaScript hacks/workarounds here. It would also break your application in case that the client has JavaScript disabled.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work. Dunno if it's no more supported or somewhat, but for me `String bt` is always `null`

Comment: It will be `null` if the button is not being used to submit the form. E.g. when you still keep using `form.submit()` like OP did. Just get rid of that part then.

Answer (score -3):

You need to convert the button parameter to String using .toString(). There is nothing wrong with your code.