# How to use single Servlet with different URL pattern?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I need to use a single servlet with different URL pattern. I have given try in the tomcat server as below. but I want to know the real coding standard please help me out?

```
String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
    
    if("/HelloServletone".equalsIgnoreCase(servletPath))
    {
        System.err.println("1?*");
                ///logic move to controller one

    }
    
    if("/HelloServlettwo".equalsIgnoreCase(servletPath))
    {
           System.err.println("2*");
           ///logic move to controller two
    }
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloServletone</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloServlettwo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

jsp1:

```
<form method="post" action="HelloServletone">
  //getting inputs and move to servlet
<input type="submit" value="login " />
```

jsp2:

```
<form method="post" action="HelloServlettwo">
  //getting inputs and move to servlet
```

Comment: I the servlet does two different things based on the path used to invoke it, why not create two different servlets?

Comment: Nizet my aim is using single servlet and having mutiple controller.. for each different jsp..

Comment: Unless this is for learning, you're reinventing the wheel. Use an MVC framework which will do it for you: Stripes, Spring MVC, Struts2, whatever.

Comment: so your suggestion is, have to use different servlet for different logic... is there is any way to define  different methods in servlet and calling it from different jsp... if yes, we can use single servlet right any thoughts NIzet?

Comment: That's the kind of functionality that is offered  by an MVC framework like Stripes, Spring MVC, etc. Unless you're trying to implement such a framework for fun or to learn, pick one of them (Stripes is very easy and really well designed) and use it.

Comment: yes thanks JB for your good reply(i aware of struts2).

Comment: Don't waste your time in finding standard way... 
(Unless you are a PM with lot of time...:)). Standard comes when you follow a specific framework..

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, what if I have the same servlet but I need to authenticate it using a filter for some clients(e.g my apps) but not for a webhook from say the payment gateway I am using. That is a valid use case for different url-patterns but the same servlet, right?

Answer (score 15):

you can use multiple URL's in one servlet mapping.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/HelloServletOne</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/HelloServletTwo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: ramesh even i done the same.... but could u please tell me how to handle these url pattern in single servlet...

Comment: ramesh my need is passing this url pattern from different jsp and identifying  it in servlet... in standard way..

Comment: like..., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912371/how-to-get-the-button-value-from-jsp-to-servlet