# how to get button value in servlet

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the button value from jsp to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912371/how-to-get-the-button-value-from-jsp-to-servlet)
>   `<script language="javascript">`enter code here`
>   function validate(){document.forms["myform"].submit();}

Here I pass the text value and with  button value to servlet. 
**Html Code:**

**servlet Code :**
    String buttonCheck=request.getParameter("custombutton");
**Output:**
`Your button Value:"null"`
But here I get button value is null, how to get button value in servlet

Comment: how are u submitting the form, I do not see submit button here, or js