# cant get submit button value in jsp? got null output

Tags: jsp

```
  for(FileModel rm:msgList)
       {
          %> 
        <Td width="5"><%=i%></Td>  
            <Td width="2000"><%=rm.getFileName()%></Td>
            <td width="2000"><%=rm.getFileDate()%></td>


         <Td><input type="image" src="images/download.png" value="<%=rm.getFileId()%>" name="download" alt="Submit Form" width="200" height="30"></Td>

          </tr><% 
               i=i+1;
           }%>
```

Comment: What about the other fields ? Are you getting the values for `getFileName()` and `getFileDate()` ?

Comment: Where is `submit` button?

Comment: yes.... got other fields... image

Comment: yes... got other result

Comment: it aiso act like submit button

Comment: String id=request.getParameter("download");
  System.out.println("gfedwsrg");
  System.out.println(id);

Comment: bt got result like  // gfedwsrg
null

Comment: input type="image" alt="Submit Form" its acts like submit form

Comment: `<button type="submit" name="foo" value="bar">
    <img src="image.png" alt="submit">
</button>`

Comment: <button type="submit" name="download" value=<%=rm.getFileId()%>> <img src="images/download.png" alt="submit" width="200" height="30"> </button>

Comment: <button type="submit" name="download" value=<%=rm.getFileId()%>> <img src="images/download.png" alt="submit" width="200" height="30"> </button> then how access value of button in servlet

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String id=request.getParameter("download");
  System.out.println("gfedwsrg");
  System.out.println(id);
 }

Comment: but I got the result like this... gfedwsrg
null

Comment: Please refer these links:[enter link description here][1] && [accessing-post-variables-using-java-servlets][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912371/how-to-get-the-button-value-from-jsp-to-servlet
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222/accessing-post-variables-using-java-servlets

Hope this helps!

Comment: not good...... tell me another method