# request.getParameter("Submit") always get null

Tags: java, servlets, null

I have this code and I'm having the null pointer error, this is suppose to get the name of the submit and act in consequence but it only gets null.
Here is the servlet:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String peticion=request.getParameter("Submit");
        ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd;
switch(peticion){
            case "registrar":
                rd=sc.getRequestDispatcher("/CreaVotante");
                rd.forward(request,response);
            break;
        }
```

Here is the submit line:

```
<input type="Submit" name="registrar" value="Regístrate para votar">
```

The submit is into a form.

Comment: Duplicated see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912371/how-to-get-the-button-value-from-jsp-to-servlet

Comment: The problem is that I don't really understand how that solution fits my problem, I'm really new with java.

Comment: Plus I have more than one submit.

Comment: @RomeoSheshi Not a duplicate of that one. It's about a non-submit button. This question is about an unnamed submit button.

Comment: The `<input>` button has no name, so it doesn't post any value. How could it, without a name?? Give it a `name="foo"` attribute if you want it to post the string value `"Regístrate para votar"` with the parameter name `"foo"`. What the point of that would be is a bit unclear, though.

Comment: I have give it a name and it keeps doing the same.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a dispatcher for a menu so I really need to get the name of the submit

Comment: The name you gave it is `registrar` not `Submit`.

Comment: So I can't look for the type?

Comment: No, it can't do that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your form example, the way to extract the parameter would be

```
String param=request.getParameter("registrar");
```